# Kruskal-Wallis Test: Identically Shaped Distributions

Tags: hypothesis-testing, nonparametric, median, kruskal-wallis-test, stochastic-ordering

I'm currently working with the Kruskall-Wallis test and had a question about what people mean when they speak about 'Identically Shaped Distributions' and how I could identify whether my data fits this description or not.

Firstly, I'm fully aware that the Kruskall-Wallis test is used to test whether there is evidence that one sample stochastically dominates another. However, it is commonly understood that if the samples are identically shaped to one-another that the Kruskall-Wallis test can be used to test for differences in medians, more specifically.

In my specific problem, it would be nice if I were able to test for evidence in differences between medians rather than just for evidence of stochastic dominance. But in order to test this, as mentioned above, I would need my data to be identically shaped to one-another.

My first question is: What does this mean for my data to be identically shaped to one-another?

And my second question is: How can I test whether my data is identically shaped *enough*, to carry on with the median test? Is there some formal test I could use, rather than just plotting the data and making a subjective judgement?

Thanks in advance!